# How can I make this link work?

Tags: html, css

I have this site (NSFW):

[link](http://www.altradona.ro/)

When the user clicks on a product, should lead to the product page. Unfortunately it does not work... and the problem is because of this code.

```
.products-grid li.item:hover:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    z-index: 10; //If we delete this code, the link works
    background: url("http://www.altradona.ro/media/wysiwyg/OVERLAY.png");
}
.products-grid li.item .product-info{
    position: relative;

}
.products-grid li:nth-of-type(-n+4):hover:before
{
height: 83.4% !Important;
}

.item:hover .product-name{
display : none;
}

.item:hover .price-box{
display : none;
}
```

If you delete the marked code, the link works but overlay effect disappears.
How can I make both things work? both link and overlay effect.

Can you tell me please how should I modify this code?

Comment: put the overlay on the link before instead  of the li before (and make the link display block with a width and height of 100%;)

Comment: Could have added that the page has nsfw content haha.. Some of us are at their office. :(

Comment: @Pete Can you tell me exactly what class should change?

Comment: so I must remove the z-index: 10? no? and then what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.products-grid li.item .product-image,
.products-grid li.item .product-image > img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.products-grid li.item .product-image:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2 background: url("http://www.altradona.ro/media/wysiwyg/OVERLAY.png");
}
```

and remove the styles for

```
.products-grid li.item:hover:before
.products-grid li.item .product-info
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 z-index: 10; //If we delete this code, the link works
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element

If if you increase the z-index of product link more than 10 then link will work.

Try this for Product link Z-index:

```
z-index:12;
```

Comment: .products-grid li.item:hover:before {z-index:12;} so you mean?